# Creating block queues with completion

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I want to create 2 async queues with completion blocks and after finished this blocks I want to run some action. I can not achieve it with this code. Where my bad?

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.queue", 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

    // block 1  
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

        [[WebRequests sharedInstance] request:@{@"type" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:request_uploadAdv], @"adv" : adv} withCompletion:^(id response) {
            BOOL success = [response boolValue];
            NSLog(@"done1 text");
             // block 1  Done
        }];
    });


    // block 2 //картинки
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

    [self getImagesForAdv:adv completion:^(NSArray *images) {
        [[WebRequests sharedInstance] uploadPhotos:images completion:^(BOOL success) {

            uploadImagesSuccess = YES;
            NSLog(@"done1 2\n");
       // block 2  Done
        }];
    }];

});

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    printf("all tasks are finished!\n");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you're missing a `});` in there somewhere. Second, there's no need for the outer `dispatch_group_async` call anyway. Assuming it's there because you want these things to execute with background priority, you can do this instead:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.company.queue", 0);
dispatch_set_target_queue(queue, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0));
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

// block 1
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

    [[WebRequests sharedInstance] request:@{@"type" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:request_uploadAdv], @"adv" : adv} withCompletion:^(id response) {
        BOOL success = [response boolValue];
        NSLog(@"done1 text");
        // block 1  Done
    }];
});


// block 2 //картинки
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{

    [self getImagesForAdv:adv completion:^(NSArray *images) {
        [[WebRequests sharedInstance] uploadPhotos:images completion:^(BOOL success) {

            uploadImagesSuccess = YES;
            NSLog(@"done1 2\n");
            // block 2  Done
        }];
    }];

});

dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    printf("all tasks are finished!\n");
});
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Just curious: if we wanted to get back on the main queue in `dispatch_group_notify`, could we set up another target queue targeting the main queue and use that in the second parameter of `dispatch_group_notify` (i.e. `dispatch_group_notify(group, mainQueue)`? I know it is redundant to create another queue as `mainQueue` and then use another `dispatch_set_target_queue` with it. But just wanted to know if it would be correct to do theoretically. Thanks.